# QNAP TS-419p as a VPN Gateway?

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, router, network-attached-storage

I am hoping one of you might be able to help.

I want to make files stored on shared folders on a QNAP TS-409p available to users over a VPN link. How is the possible?

Can someone explain what I need to do. What do I need to do at the router and what do I need to do on the QNAP NAS?

Effectively, what I want do do is use the built in Windows vpn client to connect to my home network and then be able to browse the shared folders.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since QNAP TS-419p supports Optware (QPKG) - you can try to install Open VPN package as described [here](http://wiki.nas-portal.org/index.php/Install_OpenVPN_on_QNAP)

Comment: Argh... You want to connect with Windows VPN client. It's not compatible with OpenVPN and you should use OpenVPN own client instead.

Answer (score 0):

The features listed here [QNAP TS-419p Features](http://www.qnap.com/pro_detail_feature.asp?p_id=127) don't include VPN gateway.  You could use FTP from the remote network instead.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I wonder if the OS can be extended to install OpenVPN or similar

Comment: I would put the energy into something designed to do what you need rather than something that isn't, no need to reinvent the wheel here.  Watchguard, Sonicwall, Untangle or a roll your own Linux box are some options depending on budget and DIY interests.