# QNAP TS-419 QTS 4.1.2 Using OpenVPN to Connect as a VPN Client

Tags: linux, openvpn, network-attached-storage, qnap

I'm following up on a similar user request:
[QNAP TS-419p as a VPN Gateway?](https://serverfault.com/questions/183169/qnap-ts-419p-as-a-vpn-gateway)

I have a QNAP TS-419 II, with Firmware 4.1.2. 
I have a VPN service provider than uses OpenVPN to connect to their VPN services.
Within the files given I have a ca.crt, myUser.crt, myUser.key, and a bunch of opvn configuration files for proxied or fully routed vpn connections.

I have rather followed these instructions:
http://support.purevpn.com/qnap-nas-qts-4-x-openvpn-setup-guide

When I click connect and failed after a few minutes. The following are the output within the log:

```
Sun Aug  9 00:40:02 2015 OpenVPN 2.2.1-8+deb7u3 arm-none-linux-gnueabi [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Aug  4 2015
Sun Aug  9 00:40:02 2015 WARNING: file '/share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/pass1.txt' is group or others accessible
Sun Aug  9 00:40:02 2015 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sun Aug  9 00:40:02 2015 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Sun Aug  9 00:40:02 2015 WARNING: file '/share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/vpn.key' is group or others accessible
Sun Aug  9 00:40:02 2015 Control Channel Authentication: using '/share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/vpn.key' as a free-form passphrase file
Sun Aug  9 00:40:02 2015 Key file '/share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/vpn.key' used in --tls-auth contains insufficient key material [keys found=1 required=2] -- try generating a new key file with 'openvpn --genkey --secret [file]', or use the existing key file in bidirectional mode by specifying --tls-auth without a key direction parameter
```

For the Warnings, I understand it is a file permission issue, can someone tell me what it should be?

For the Note and OpenVPN security suggestion, does anyone know what I am suppose to do from that point on to get it working properly?

My Client configuration file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
tls-client
remote <remote IP> 80
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/ca.crt
tls-auth /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/key.key
cert /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/cert.crt
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
auth-user-pass /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/pass1.txt
auth-retry interact
script-security 3
log-append /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/openvpn.log
verb 3
mute 20
keepalive 10 60
writepid /var/run/openvpn.client.pid
up /etc/openvpn/openvpn_up
down /etc/openvpn/openvpn_down
explicit-exit-notify 2
ifconfig-nowarn
auth-nocache
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the first warning, you should add `ns-cert-type server` to your client config [OpenVPN Manual][1]

As per the last line, you need to regenerate one of your keys, **or** change your config:

1. `openvpn --genkey --secret /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/vpn.key ;`  **or**
2. Remove the number from behind `--tls-auth` in your client config.

You need to then  remove `Group` and `Other` rights from the 2 keyfiles:

`chmod go= /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/pass1.txt ;`

`chmod go= /share/MD0_DATA/Download/vpn/vpn.key ;`

That will take care of "group or others accessible"

```
[1][https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#mitm]
```

By the way, this is more-or-less a dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57798/openvpn-warning-no-server-certificate-verification-method-has-been-enabled

Comment: my keys are given to me by the VPN provider. So wouldnt the regenerating it won't allow me to negotiate with the server?

Comment: it is similar but not a duped, because there might be some extra steps pertaining to QNAP connections to make it work (like editing autorun.sh for example)

Comment: Have you managed to get it working?

Comment: Negative, I have logged into the console and openvpn is no longer within the path (global) but yet when i do a opkg install again, it says that it is installed and all my path is correct. I did change the chmod to 400 on the key/pass1.txt as suggested.

Comment: Did you also execute the other commands? So, the binary has disappeared? An a reinstall does not reinstate the openvpn binary?